# amazon s3 forbidden 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, http-status-code-403, wimpy

I have uploaded a bunch of files from my local into amazon using paperclip. So far there are no problems accessing them, but there are some "stray" objects that when you access them, will give you a forbidden 403 response.

These files are mp3s and if their urls return a 403 forbidden, my player) wimpy player, crashes. IS there a valid reason why only some of the files return a 403? if so, how do i fix it?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same type of problems. Were you ever able to find a solution to your issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ACL settings for those files. Use a GUI such as the AWS console for this. Are the file names spelt exactly as you think? - no extra spaces?

Are you using private files with generated expiring urls? Check that the generated querystring doesn't have 'invalid' characters like `+` in it. I have seen media players choking on some of these before.

Comment: ive checked on these and it doesn't seem that way. all the files are uploaded via rake task and we've specifically checked that certain file's ACL settings and compared it to another which was working. they both have the same settings, filename structure etc.

Comment: @corroded - are the files publicly accessible or private?

Comment: yup they are publicly accessible

Comment: @corroded - Can you get to the files that are 403ing using a generated scure url?

Comment: nope, it's the same...i cant get to the files with 403 using the url but i can get to the others. i dont know whats wrong with their permissions and why they are the only ones affected

Comment: Weird - I'm sort of out of ideas then... try uploading one of those files again manually using the aws console. Maybe that will determine if its the file or the upload process thats to blame.

Comment: should i upload to the same folder? right now it seems aws has a separate folder for each file

Comment: @corroded - S3 doesn't actually have a concept of folders. You have buckets (which are globally unique - you can create 100) and keys/files which go in buckets. However if you use `/` in your filenames, you can mimic folders. All the gui tools recognise this and display a folder hierarchy rather than just the filename. So a file named `myfolder/myfilename.mp3` will appear to be in a folder called `myfolder`. So after all that, can you give an example of a filename and the url you are using to access it?